# Missing brushes for Texture painting in 2.8

Tags: texture-painting

I downloaded Blender 2.8 and I wanted do some texture painting. But I noticed that there's only 1 brush in my Blender.

[image: This is Blender 2.8]

There was more brushes in Blender 2.79.

[image: This is Blender 2.79]

Where are all the brushes gone? I need them.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please do not use caps in your titles. Using caps online is usually considered as the written equivalent of shouting loudly, and shouting is frowned upon. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The tool has changed a bit, and things are now in a different place.

Simply, this in 2.79:

[image]

has become this is 2.8:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The latest builds of Blender now treat each of those brushes as their own tool - so  if you are drawing/painting, the default tool is that initial brush TexDraw and you will be able to make multiple versions of it that will now be handled as brushes. This is more in line with Photoshop and other software in that the blur tool, the mask tool, and the smear tool, clone tool, etc. are separate tools with all their own settings and functions. A better design that actually means we have to get used to the new tool paradigm, this also means it will be easier to manage brushes once we have the asset manager. You will be able to select the TexDraw tool and then in the tool properties select an individual brush there.

Comment: a little gift to complete your answer: https://i.imgur.com/1sNyNzC.png

Answer (score 0):

Just open the tool menu by pushing U button. 
then press X button